# How to determine which API is going to return the result first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Let us assume that we are making 2 API calls, each will take say 6ms to return JSON data. What the order in which they are going to return the resultant data.

I have read in the official documentation that Promise.all is used in JavaScript to handle multiple API calls.

Comment: Using Promise.all means that it doesn't matter which finishes first.  Both have to complete before calling the callback and the responses are mapped 1:1 with the array of promises fed and in the same order.  There is no way to tell which will complete first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make two API calls one after the other to the same target server, you have no way to know which will return its result first. That depends entirely upon the target server and how it does its processing for each API call.  It could be that one will always return first or it could be random which returns first.

`Promise.all()` is typically used when you want to track multiple asynchronous operations and you want to know when all of them are complete.  `Promise.allSettled()` is sometimes also used, depending upon what type of behavior you want when there is an error in one of the calls.

For example, if you were using the promise-based [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to make your API calls and you were expecting JSON results, you could do this:

```
const got = require('got');

Promise.all([got(url1).json(), got(url2).json()]).then([result1, result2] => {
    console.log(result1, result2);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

In this usage of `Promise.all()`, `result1, result2` will be in the order you made the requests, regardless of which one finished first so `result1` will always be the result of `got(url1).json()` and `result2`, the second request.  This is one of the things that `Promise.all()` does for you (puts the results into the order they were requested, regardless of what order they actually completed).